# Call Kotlin function with Lambda parameters in Java

Tags: java, kotlin

How do I call Kotlin functions with lambdas in the parameter from a Java class.

Example

```
fun getToken(
        tokenUrl: String,
        onSuccess: (String) -> Unit,
        onError: (Error) -> Unit
    ): Provider {
        //Implementation
    }
```

Comment: A lambda is just a closure in Kotlin

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this

```
    value.getToken("url",
    new Function1<String, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(String s) {
            /* TODO */
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    }, new Function1<Throwable, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(Throwable throwable) {
            /* TODO */
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `return Unit.INSTANCE;` in the invoke method.

Comment: This comment should be part if the answer. @Francesc can you please update your answer to include the comment? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can call it with normal Java 8 lambdas, since Kotlin is actually using a single-method interface on the backend.

```
myFoo.getToken(tokenUrl, successString -> { ... }, error -> { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately my project is not set to Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

This is for calling it within Kotlin, the question was edited to say "from Java" after I provided my answer. Leaving it here anyway in hope that it is useful.

You can call it like this

```kotlin
fun test() {

    getToken("asdf", { print(it) }, { println(it) })

    getToken("asdf", { print(it) }) { err -> println(err) }

    getToken("asdf", ::println, ::println)

    getToken("asdf", ::println) { println(it) }
}
```

Comment: I know how to call it within Kotlin. I want to call the function from a Java class.

Comment: Your original question was edited.  Before it didn't say from Java.  I think the downvotes I received were unnecessary.

Comment: it did, but it was only in the title. I added it in the body after you answered it incorrectly for additional clarification. `Call Kotlin function with Lambda parameters in Java`. I think your downvote of my question is unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.  Also I assumed other people downvoted my answer since you had the full context and would understand why my answer was seemingly incorrect.